# Problems with an external API in ADALO

Tags: api

I made a c # API that inserts and updates data in SQL server. I have tested this API with Postman and it works. I introduced this API in a custom action in ADALO and it works with the sample data. When I call the custom action from the click of a button, the API does not work giving a 500 internal server error, even if using the same example data that worked previously. I cannot understand what this could depend on.
I thank in advance who will help me.

Comment: Are you running the API locally? Is anything reported in the server logs? have you tried debugging the issue and comparing the request with your Postman request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.